# How to draw periodic bonds in Visual Molecular Dynamics (VMD)?

Tags: visualization-software, vmd, periodic-boundary-conditions

I have the LAMMPS DUMP file of a salt solution, and I am investigating the Oligomerization of the salt ions in solution. However, when I am trying to visualize the trajectory, I can only draw bonds that are within the original box. Is there a way to draw the periodic bonds, or bonds that can go between the periodic images?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I have had the same problem. As a workaround, I have just used VESTA for those cases that I really wanted to see the bonds. Hope this helps!

Comment: @TySterling I am very curious why you didn't upvote if you have had the same problem?

Comment: Hemanth, congrats on reaching 3000!

Comment: Good point @Ihavenofreetimeanymore ! Upvoted.